# copy activity failed due to csv file issue?

Tags: azure-data-factory

Copy activity failed with csv issue
ErrorCode=DelimitedTextMoreColumnsThanDefined,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Error found when processing 'Csv/Tsv Format Text' source 'abc.csv' with row number 2571: found more columns than expected column count 136.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,'.
I am using a copy activity with source as csv files from adls and sink as SQL DB. I got the above error. Column counts are exactly matching. When i try to load the same file in excel format to sql db, its working perfectly fine. Why am I getting issue only in csv, quite not sure

Comment: can u share the input excel and output excel sample data

Answer (score 0):

based on the error message it seems that your data has a column delimiter value within it.
Like lets say data has value 'a,bc' and your column delimiter is comma (,)

The solution for that is have a diff delimiter or use quote char